# Tracking Loan Made to someone in Mint

Tags: loans

I loaned my son money for his car and he is now paying this back with monthly payments. Is there a way to track that within Mint? Tried setting up different account types, but none of them seem correct.

Comment: If you can't do it in Mint, then Google Sheets will work.  That's how we tracked the mortgage money my grandmother loaned me.  (It was a full-on official mortgage contract which specified the property, the interest rate, period and what would happen if I defaulted.)

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm doing right now, l love Excel! But if there's a way to do it in Mint with the rest of my finances that would be great.